# how to get multiple latitudinal and longitude values and mark them with markers on the map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'd like to call up the latitude and longitude on the server and mark it with a marker on the google map.What should I do?

```
stopMapActivity



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_map);
        nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.addRouteButton);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        ssm = new ServerSideMethods(this,false);
        stop_list = new ArrayList<stop_list_item>();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = 0;
                try{
                    stop_list = ssm.getCarStopList(17900);
                    msg.what = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < stop_list.size(); i++) {
                        MarkerOptions makerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        makerOptions
                                .position(new LatLng(stopListArray.get(i).get("x"), stopListArray.get(i).get("y")))
                                .title(stopListArray.get(i).get("stop_name"));

                        mGoogleMap.addMarker(makerOptions);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("[HB]"+this.getClass().getName(),"Error:"+e.toString());
                    msg.what = 0;
                }
            }
        }).start();


    }
```

error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double (.position(new LatLng(stopListArray.get(i).get("x"), stopListArray.get(i).get("y"))) this line) The code in serveridemethod is too long to post only the required part and mapactivity is the whole code.

This code will generate this error
Would it be possible to get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is inside your for loop where you are trying to pass a string as List's get() function:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < stop_list.size(); i++) {
                    MarkerOptions makerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    makerOptions
                            .position(new LatLng(stopListArray.get("x"), stopListArray.get("y")))
                            .title(stopListArray.get(i).get("stop_name")); 

                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(makerOptions);
                }
```

Instead it should be :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < stop_list.size(); i++) {
                    MarkerOptions makerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    makerOptions
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stopListArray.get(i).get("x")), Double.parseDouble(stopListArray.get(i).get("y"))))
                            .title(stopListArray.get(i).get("stop_name")); 

                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(makerOptions);
                }
```

Comment: I've tried the above method, but I'm getting an error.
        error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double

Comment: Could you please post your complete activity code with your complete error log

Comment: I've re-amended the text above.

Comment: Here, Fixed it in the above answer. LatLng class constructor takes two double parameters whereas you were passing it string values. Need to convert your string values to double